# Powershell: Filter out .tmp files for Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that filters out certain security events in the Event Viewer. Specifically, event ID 4663, to audit who deletes a file on a server share. Unfortunately, this also displays .tmp files that are deleted, which I am not concerned with.

The script works fine with filtering these events, but I cannot figure out how to filter out the .tmp events. I have tried things like `-ne`, `-match`, `-notlike`, `-notcontains` and the `!` operator, but the .tmp events still get displayed.

Here is my code:

```
$path= "C:\Path\To\Folder\Security.evtx"
$filter= "*[System[(EventID=4663)]]"
$main= Get-WinEvent -path $path -FilterXPath $filter -MaxEvents 10 | Format-List
$main | Where-Object {$_.extension -notlike "*.tmp"}
```

Any help with filtering out these .tmp deletion events would be greatly appreciated!

---

***Updated Solution

Turns out I was missing an `*` at the end of "*.tmp" and needed to include the .message property. Solution:

```
$main= Get-WinEvent -path $path -FilterXPath $filter -MaxEvents 10
$main | Where-Object {$_.Message -notlike "*.tmp*"} | Format-List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you are piping the result to `Format-List` in this line:

```
$main= Get-WinEvent -path $path -FilterXPath $filter -MaxEvents 10 | Format-List
```

By doing this the object type is changed and can no longer be filtered on it's properties. Remove `| Format-List` and/or use this cmdlet after the `Where-Object`.

Regarding filtering, I think you may need to look for *.tmp in the output of the `Message` property as follows:

```
$main | Where-Object {$_.message -notlike "*.tmp*"}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and the .tmp files still show up. I'm guessing the extension property doesn't exist? How can I pinpoint the .tmp extension, through some sort of file name property perhaps?

Comment: It might just be in the `.Message` property. Sorry I don't have somewhere with object access turned on that I can use to reproduce.

Comment: Tried both of those, same issue. This is one stubborn problem lol I'll keep playing with the properties, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Try `| Where-Object {$_.message -notlike "*.tmp*"}`. Probably needs a * both sides as it will appear in the middle of the text block.

Comment: That did it, it worked! Wow, who knew that one missing `*` would be a major cause. Thank you very much for your help!